# Django как отправить, сохранить значение формы?

Tags: django

[Нарисовал иллюстрацию к проблеме для просмотра кликните сюда](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAlwS.jpg)

Делаю опросник,

Циклом прохожу по таблице с вопросами (Metrix), ищу способ как сохранять и возвращать значения ответов value = '' (Metrix_user) на той же странице для редактирования пользователем в режиме онлайн. (в дальнейшем планирую использовать pagination с кнопками назад далее)

**My models:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Metrix(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Question')
    metrix_category = models.ForeignKey(
        'category',
        related_name='Question_category',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Category',
    )
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, 
        verbose_name='Question_category')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class User_metrix(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="user_metrix", 
        verbose_name='User')
    metrix = models.ForeignKey('Metrix', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        verbose_name='Question')
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, 
        verbose_name='Value')
```

**My view:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from metrix.models import Metrix, User_metrix

@login_required
def metrix_view(request, pk=None):
    metrix_category = {
        'pk': 4
    }

    #Get questions by category
    metrix_list = Metrix.objects.filter(is_published=True,  
         metrix_category__pk=pk)

    context = {
        'metrix_list': metrix_list
    }    
    return render(request, 'metrix/metrix.html', context)
```

**Template:**
Получаю вопросы в цикле  "metrix_list" из таблицы Metrix
Ищу способ сохранять значение  value и возвращать его пользователю (данное значение должно храниться в таблице Metrix_user)

```
            <!--cycle for metrix-->
            {% for item in metrix_list %}

            <div class="row metrix_quiestion_line justify-content-center">
                <div class="metrix_quiestion">
                    <h2>
                    {{ item }}
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="metrix_value">
                    <input type="number" name="{{ item.id }}" value=" ">
                </div>
            </div>

            {% endfor %}

            <!--END cycle -->
```